# Liquid can lift a small piece of paper?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

Imagine you have a small piece of paper in your hand. Your hands are sweaty and due to perspiration, the paper kind of bends up. Can you explain what is happening? Is it the capillary forces?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because paper is hydrophilic and absorbs moisture emitted from your skin. As the paper absorbs moisture it swells. The side nearer your skin absorbs moisture faster than the side farther from your skin, so the side nearer your skin swells more rapidly and this causes the paper to bend.

The actual motion can be quite complicated because paper is a tangled mass of cellulose fibres and exactly how it bends will depend on how those fibres interact with each other as they swell.

Comment: What do you mean with 'side nearest your skin', it is flat in your hand. Can you please elaborate your answer a bit?

Answer (score 1):

No. In this case the moisture sweat from your hand causes the near side of the paper to expand, which makes the paper curve upwards. This is because one side of the paper has expanded while the other is still dry and has not.

"Capillary forces" is not a term I would use, but essentially it refers to force of surface tension, which depend on whether the liquid wets the surface it is in contact with. When wetting take place, the molecular forces between the liquid and the surface are greater than the molecular forces between the liquid and itself. So, if your sweat wets the paper, the paper will stick to your hand.